# How do I build a WAS 6.1 specific EAR without RSA/RAD?

Tags: java, ant, websphere, ear, websphere-6.1

Are there some IBM ant tasks that support this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebSphere comes with its own version of Ant (that you can use by executing the `ws_ant.bat/sh` file) and a set of [Ant tasks](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/public_html/api/com/ibm/websphere/ant/tasks/package-summary.html). Have a look at the following resources for more practical details:

- [Automate Web services with Ant and WebSphere](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0606_ulbricht/0606_ulbricht.html#download)
- [Ant: automated deployment to WebSphere Application Server](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2008/08/ant-automated-deployment-to-websphere.html)